# Compare two columns to return equal values in both

Tags: r

I have four ID columns in my table (called MGIT): Ext_ID_1 through _4. Sometimes the same number is present in different rows in them and I need to filter these rows for further analysis, example:

Starting state:

```
Ext_ID      Ext_ID_4

1111          2222
3333          4444
5555          1111
6666          7777
8888          9999
9999          1010
```

Desired filtered outcome:

```
Ext_ID      Ext_ID_4

1111          2222
5555          1111
8888          9999
9999          1010
```

I would only like to compare them two at a time for clearer management.

Through previous questions in StackOverflow I have found the following code:

```
Dupl = MGIT[,c('Ext_ID','Ext_ID_4')]
Result <- MGIT[duplicated(Dupl) | duplicated(Dupl, fromLast=TRUE),]
```

But it's giving back duplicated only values *inside* the columns (actually, only inside Ext_ID, but I believe ID_4 doesn't have duplicated values within itself).

I am a beginner at programming and know nothing about the language.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want this to work for all your four columns, and not just the two in your example.

Here is a solution that will work no matter how many "Ext_ID" columns you have:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Recreate the data from your example
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Ext_ID,      ~Ext_ID_4,
  1111,          2222,
  3333,          4444,
  5555,          1111,
  6666,          7777,
  8888,          9999,
  9999,          1010
)

# The actual code you need - just replace `df` with the name of your table
df %>% 
  filter(
    if_any(
      starts_with("Ext_ID"),
      ~ .x %>% purrr::map_lgl(~sum(df == .x) > 1)
    )
  )

# The output:
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Ext_ID Ext_ID_4
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1   1111     2222
#> 2   5555     1111
#> 3   8888     9999
#> 4   9999     1010
```

Explaination:

- `~ .x %>% purrr::map_lgl(~sum(df == .x) > 1)` checks whether each value in a column shows up more than once in the dataframe.
- `starts_with("Ext_ID")` makes sure that this is done for all columns starting with "Ext_ID"
- `if_any()` makes `filter()` keep rows where there are at least 1 duplicate value in the df for any of the columns.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention my table has >9000 characters so the first part of your code is actually difficult to pull off. The second part seems to be dependent on it. Is there any way to apply this strategy to larger datasets?

Comment: Hi @BarbaraMateosPerezdeAraújo. I'm unsure what you mean by "characters". Do you mean that you have >9000 rows/observations, >9000 columns/variables, or that each value in e.g. `Ext_ID` consists of >9000 characters/letters?

Comment: And by "the first part of my code", do you mean the `tibble::tribble()` part? That is just to recreate your example data to get a reproducable example. You can ignore this in your code. Just replace `df` with the name of your table in the second part of the code. I'll add sine comments to my code to make this clear.

Comment: In short: this code should work fine with large data as well :)

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution:

```r
#Select whatever column you want
cols <- unlist(dat[, c('Ext_ID','Ext_ID_4')]) 

#Get the values that appear at least twice 
uni <- unique(cols[ave(cols, cols, FUN=length) > 1]) 

#Filter if any of the row values match with uni
dat[apply(apply(dat, 1, function(x) x %in% uni), 2, any), ] 
  Ext_ID Ext_ID_4
1   1111     2222
3   5555     1111
5   8888     9999
6   9999     1010
```

Comment: Thank you. I used your code and got desired returns, but it seems it also considered IDs such as "AAA123" and "123" as duplicates. I can't 100% say this is what happened but there was no other "123" in the table besides there. Does the code need to be tweaked to consider only entire values when comparing?

Comment: This is weird. I don't think it is due to the code, because it treats "AAA123" and "123" as different values. Maybe you could add an example in your question where this happens.